# If a table header <th> doesn't exsist, move the first child <tr><td> as <th>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Let's say I have the following table format and I want to check if the table has a `thead th`. If the table has no `thead th`, the first child of `tbody tr` would be move as `thead th`.

How to check if the table contains header?

```js
$(function() {
  var th = $('table tbody tr:first td').map(function(i, e) {
    return $('<th>').append(e.textContent).get(0);
  });
  $('table').prepend($('<thead>').append(th)).find('tr:first').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I edited your question so that the code in an executable snippet - and from that you can see that it works fine (aside from missing the `<tr>` in the appended `<thead>`). Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: I have some tables that already have a header and it's affected by the current js.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: The code does not contain a check.

Comment: @Elsk: Because your code doesn't actually check if the table has a thead first before making changes.

Comment: yes @BoltClock, how to check if the table contains header? And if there's no header, how to make the first child tr to be header?

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `thead` exists by selecting it and checking the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object.

Note that you need to wrap the `th` you append to the new `thead` with a `tr` element. I have also amended your code to work in cases where there are multiple tables in the DOM. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
    if ($table.find('thead').length)
      return;

    var th = $table.find('tbody tr:first td').map(function(i, e) {
      return $('<th />').append(e.textContent).get(0);
    });
    var $tr = $('<tr />').append(th);
    var $thead = $('<thead />').append($tr);
    $table.prepend($thead).find('tbody tr:first').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```